# Getting Error - ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

Tags: oracle

I am getting the error in the below sql:

> ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

```
SELECT   c.contract_num,
         CASE
            WHEN   (  MAX (TO_CHAR (TO_DATE (c.event_dt, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'MMDD'))
                    - MIN (TO_CHAR (TO_DATE (c.event_dt, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'MMDD')))
                 / COUNT (c.event_occurrence) < 32
            THEN
              'Monthly'
            WHEN       (  MAX (
                            TO_CHAR (TO_DATE (c.event_dt, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'MMDD'))
                        - MIN (
                            TO_CHAR (TO_DATE (c.event_dt, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'MMDD')))
                     / COUNT (c.event_occurrence) >= 32
                 AND   (  MAX (
                            TO_CHAR (TO_DATE (c.event_dt, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'MMDD'))
                        - MIN (
                            TO_CHAR (TO_DATE (c.event_dt, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'MMDD')))
                     / COUNT (c.event_occurrence) < 91
            THEN
              'Quarterley'
            ELSE
              'Yearly'
         END
FROM     ps_ca_bp_events c
GROUP BY c.contract_num;
```

Comment: What is the datatype of your event_dt column? Also, why are you converting your dates to strings and subtracting them? What is the purpose? If it's to find how many days are between the two dates, think about what result you might get if the max date was 12th December and the min date was 31st November in the same year. And what if they were in different years?

Comment: event_dt column is of Date type.

Comment: if it's already a date, why are you doing `TO_DATE` on it?!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The error you are getting is either because you are doing `TO_DATE` on a column that's already a date, and you're using a format mask that is different to your `nls_date_format` parameter[1] or because the event_occurrence column contains data that isn't a number.

You need to a) correct your query so that it's not using TO_DATE on the date column, and b) correct your data, if event_occurrence is supposed to be just numbers.

And fix the datatype of that column to make sure you can only store numbers.

[1] *What Oracle does when you do: `TO_DATE(date_column, non_default_format_mask)` is:
`TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(date_column, nls_date_format), non_default_format_mask)`*

*Generally, the default `nls_date_format` parameter is set to `dd-MON-yy`, so in your query, what is likely to be happening is your date column is converted to a string in the format dd-MON-yy, and you're then turning it back to a date using the format MMDD. The string is not in this format, so you get an error.*

Comment: I Just removed the TO_DATE() function and the query is working fine... Thanks a lot for you prompt response... I really appreciate you man!! :)

Answer (score 3):

This error can come not only because of the Date conversions

This error can come when we try to pass date whereas `varchar` is expected 
or 
when we try to pass `varchar` whereas date is expected.

Use `to_char(sysdate,'YYYY-MM-DD')` when `varchar` is expected

Answer (score 2):

I added `TO_DATE` and it resolved issue.

**Before modification** - due to below condition i got this error

```
record_update_dt>='05-May-2017'
```

**After modification** - after adding `to_date`, issue got resolved.

```
record_update_dt>=to_date('05-May-2017','DD-Mon-YYYY')
```