# ORA-01858 while executing created procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have created a procedure to find a date between `today` and `expiry_date`.
The table column format  is already  in date format.

While creating procedure it is created successfully without errors but during execution of  procedure as below it is showing

> ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT ='dd-mm-yyyy';
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE flow (
    today  IN                  DATE,
    expiry_date       IN       DATE
) AS

BEGIN
    FOR  rec in (
        SELECT *
        FROM flow4
        WHERE englishcalendar BETWEEN 'englishcalendar.today' 
                    AND 'englishcalendar.expiry_date')
    LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line(rec.englishcalendar);
    END LOOP;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
END;
/

EXEC FLOW('01-02-2017','03-04-2018');
/
```

I had also tried adding to_date in both procedure and procedure execution but i got same error 
I also tried with this reference too 
    [Getting Error - ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29852389/getting-error-ora-01858-a-non-numeric-character-was-found-where-a-numeric-was)

**NOTE** `englishcalendar` contains continuous day of 2019  in 'dd-mm-yyyy' date format

Comment: `WHERE englishcalendar BETWEEN 'englishcalendar.today' AND 'englishcalendar.expiry_date')` seems incorrect. Please share the schema of table flow4.

Comment: hr.flow4.englishcalendar.today  (Schema ==> HR , flow4 ==> Table_name, englishcalendar ==> Column name and  today ==> procedure INPARAM) @AnkitBajpai

Comment: I meant table flow4's structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'englishcalendar.today'` is a string not a date. Likewise `'englishcalendar.expiry_date'`. Oracle is attempting to convert these strings to dates and failing, because they are not dates.

Simple solution: reference the parameters as identifiers not strings:

```
 ... 
  FOR  rec in (
    SELECT *
    FROM flow4
    WHERE englishcalendar BETWEEN today
                AND expiry_date)
...
```

Comment: Thank you @APC a lot you have done great work through which i am struggling for hours  !!