# ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

Tags: sql, oracle

I am beginner in oracle and need help regarding following query:

```
select admin_id, to_date(date_created, 'DD-MM-YYYY'), name, mobile, email, (select status from status where status.status_id = admin.status_id) from admin;
```

Here are my tables:

```
SQL> desc admin
 Name                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ADMIN_ID                  NOT NULL NUMBER(5)
 STATUS_ID                 NOT NULL NUMBER(5)
 DATE_CREATED                       TIMESTAMP(6)
 STATUS_DATE                        DATE
 NAME                           VARCHAR2(45)
 MOBILE                         VARCHAR2(20)
 EMAIL                          VARCHAR2(110)

SQL> desc status
 Name                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 STATUS_ID                 NOT NULL NUMBER(5)
 STATUS                         VARCHAR2(36)
```

The main problem is I want to get status.status on basis of admin.status_id. The date could be fixed by using it as char `to_char(date_created,'DD/MM/YYYY')`

Comment: OK.  So the "main problem" has nothing to do with the error you asked about in the subject?  It appears that the last column in your query is a subquery that will give you the "status.status on basis of admin.status_id".  Normally you'd write a join for that but the subquery you wrote appears valid.  Are you getting an error?  If so, what error?  Are you not getting the results you expect?  If so, post some sample data and the expected output for that sample data.

Comment: @JustinCave Thanks from the bottom of my heart. You are right there was misunderstanding about the question title and original problem that I was facing. Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`to_date(date_created, 'DD-MM-YYYY')` doesn't make a whole lot of sense.

- `date_created` is a `timestamp` with 6 decimal digits of sub-second precision.
- `to_date` takes a string.  So Oracle has to first convert the timestamp to a string using the session's `nls_timestamp_format`.  That is the string that gets sent to `to_date`.
- `to_date` then tries to convert that string back to a `date` (which will always have a time component) using the "DD-MM-YYYY" format mask.  Unless that happens to be what your `nls_timestamp_format` is set to, that conversion will fail and will probably throw the error you reported.

If all this casting worked, you'd end up sending the Java application a date that has the time set to midnight.  As a general rule, though, it would normally make more sense to just send the timestamp back to the Java application and let it handle how to convert that to a string and what components of the timestamp needed to be shown.  So my default would be to just select `date_created`.

If you really want Oracle to do the data type conversion and to set the time component of the `date` to midnight, you can use `trunc` and `cast` instead.  This avoids implicit data type conversion and eliminates dependencies on the session's `nls_timestamp_format`.

```
trunc( cast( date_created as date ) )
```

Comment: The main problem is not that could be fixed with `to_char(date_created, 'dd/mm/yyyy')` My main problem is getting status_id record based on one table from another table

Comment: @user230 - I'm not sure I understand.  Are you saying that you have problems with the query you posted beyond the particular error you indicated?  If so, what problems?  Are there additional errors?  Are you not getting the results you expect?

Comment: Please check I mentioned my main problem in the question

Answer (score -1):

1. Check the values in the `admin_id` and `status_id` columns. Make sure they are correct data types.
2. Can you rearrange the query below and check output. Try to use join where possible instead of the nested query to improve the performance of the database:

   ```
   select ad.admin_id, to_date(ad.date_created, 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 
          ad.name, ad.mobile, ad.email,st.status  
   from admin ad,status st 
   where ad.admin_id=st.status_id;
   ```
3. Here is link for a similar issue: [Getting Error - ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29852389/getting-error-ora-01858-a-non-numeric-character-was-found-where-a-numeric-was/29852888) (Stackoverflow)

Comment: thanks but this is not what I am looking for. This query will compare both table status_id whereas I want to display admin record + admin(foreign Key) status_id `status` from status table. Please check both tables structure. I listed in my question